# XHRs from an outside js file makes app crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an `api.js` file where I make a couple of XHR-equests. I was using it inside a **script tag** inside an `.ejs` file, but it was getting too crowded. So after I moved everything to the `api.js` I'm no longer able to access its data.

Every time I try to require it from my `app.js` my program crashes.`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...` I've tried putting it inside my `public` folder and some other places, but it never works.

Should I export the data from `api.js` like I would if it was a data schema? If so, how would I do that? (something like `module.exports = mongoose.model("Data", dataSchema);` ? I don't have any models in `api.js`, it's just a couple of requests)

The `.ejs` file that is supposed to make use of `api.js` has a route like this:

```
app.get('/home', function(req, res){
    res.render('home', { moment: moment }); //home is an .ejs file
});
```

The `{ moment: moment }` is from moment.js.,.if I'm supposed to export `api.js`, how could I use it in this  route since I'm already using `moment.js`. I think I can't just do

```
res.render('home', { moment: moment }, {api: api});
```

The main problem might be the app crashing since without solving this issue I won't be able to solve anything else.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much of the process you understand, but your ejs file is a "template" --- you pass "variables" to it and "render" it, and then express sends the html file. After it renders it, the "variables" are no longer accessible unless they're passed into a `<script>` tag like you might be doing. (I'm not sure how you're using `moment` --- or maybe you only use `moment` to render something server side)

Instead of trying to pass `api`, your html file can use the script tag, which can refer to other files like

```
<script src='/js/api.js'></script>
```

But your server (through express.js) needs to serve this file.

That is the common option, and should work for you.

You generally don't "pass" a module or library to the template engine unless you need it to render something. But if you wanted to, you can also read the api.js file as a string and "inject" it into the script tag... (I don't usually see it done this way)

```
<script><%= api %></script>
```

Comment: I'm using the script tag in the .ejs file, but still doesn't work. The "final product" of the api.js is something like this `money2.innerText = moneyData2.USD_BRL;` (there are a couple of these, and money2 is a from a querySelector)...I've also tryied using this code inside  these tags `<%= %>` but I get an error.

Comment: I've never tried using {{api}} like this in any othe scenario. Do you think it'd work in this case? Something like {{moneyData2.USD_BRL}}?

Comment: Sorry I'm not actually super familiar with ejs's variable syntax, I use pug which is somewhat similar. Updated

Comment: If you're going to inject it, it HAS to be a `string`, not an `object`